# Tracking actions in a browser component

Tags: c#, .net, interop, browser, webkit

Im a c# developer and I *believe* that what I want to achieve is going to move out of the realms of some drop in .NET component so I am looking for advise on what I use externally which .NET can inter op with.

My requirements are to have an embedded web browser control in a WPF/Winforms applciation **BUT** I will also need to keep track of the following:

1. User interaction i.e. what pages they visit, forms submitted where they click etc.
2. DOM manipulation and traversing

I am guessing here but it seems that I might need to start looking at open source html/web browsers out there like WebKit etc. Is this the right track or is there anything currently available in the form of a control/COM object that I can use directly.

Cheers, Chris.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish point 1 using the webbrowser control in Visual Studio, but I dont think DOM manipulation is available, i do know you can traverse all the tags.
[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_members.aspx)

Comment: I'd need both, for example Id want an event to be fired when I'm hovering over an image that in turn surrounds that image with a big red border.